# Starting a team project collection after detaching and attaching again

Tags: team-foundation-server

I recently detached a team project collection using Team Foundation Admin Console and made a backup of the database and then reattached the same collection. After compeleting the attachment, an error occurred in Team Foundation that the collection cannot be started. After that whenever I try to start the collection again, it says: "**TF400783: The host '[CollectionName]' cannot be started. The host is in the process of being serviced. The servicing may have failed and needs to be restarted and completed before the host can be started.**".

[image]

I also tried to delete the team project using TFSUtil.exe with no luck at all.
I'm stuck and don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to phone Microsoft support. They van fix this for you.

Comment: Mr Hinsh is correct: open a MS support call.

Answer (score 0):

1. GO to Team Foundation Collections.
2. Select the collection that
   is offline (the one which is giving an error while being started)
3. Now go to Status tab down below (there will be more tabs like
   General, Status, Team Projects)
4. Select the job that is failed (mostly Apply Patch job)
5. Click on the Rerun Job button on the right.

Your collection will be ready, now say thanks to me if it works ;)

Comment: Hi! I did that in my case and get a error message: `[Error] TF400868: Job definition not found for JobId d891ac97-ddf1-42df-8242-3cd4bd607790.` Any Idea what this is referring to? Also, if I go to `Team Projects` tab is just one project and the state is `Deleting`